# Only allow users to view the site when using an Iframe inside another site

Tags: wordpress

I created a wordpress blog, but need to allow the users to view the blog, only if they are accessing the site using an iframe that is on another site. Im treing to find out a solution for this, but couldnt come up with any ideas.

Any ideas ?

Thanks
Bruno

Answer (score 0):

You could check the parent URL from the IFrame.

So mysite.com has an iframe called blog.somewhere.com

in blog.somewhere.com you check the parent frame URL and if it is not mysite.com you redirect the user somewhere else (probably to mysite.com frontpage)

Hope you can make it work

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. How would i do that ? using javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra query var to the query string, then check if it exists in your header.php file. If not, display an error telling the user how to view the site.